# How to select BIT columns as TRUE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table called TP_Roles.

This Table structure is:

```
 Id PK, int, not null
 Role_Name  varchar(200), null
 IsActive   bit, null
```

How Do I insert bit value as True instead of 1 ?

Many thanks.

Comment: `BIT` value `1` corresponds to `TRUE` and `0` corresponds to `FALSE`

Comment: but i insert 1  after view table i can view 1 only i can't able to view True

Comment: yes. You can only be able to see `0/1` in the bit value column.

Comment: MYSql <> sql server.

Comment: sql server 2014@ZoharPeled

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`BIT` values are `1/0` and they correspond to `TRUE/FALSE` accordingly.

By the comments I assume you want to view `TRUE` / `FALSE` when selecting this column, so you can simply use a `CASE EXPRESSION` for this:

```
SELECT <Column1>,<Column2>...,
       CASE WHEN IsActive = 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END as IsActive
FROM YourTable
```

If `IsActive = 1` - display `TRUE` , else , display `FALSE`.

Comment: I have one more doubt Sagi

Comment: Sorry I'm not following, try to explain better or open a new question with all the necessary data. @thenna

Comment: Ok Sagi i wll post new question

Comment: I posted new question Sagi here link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302486/foreign-key-relationship-in-two-table