# how to make FOREIGN KEY Relationship in Two table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database

I have creating database name called montage. same database hosted server . i cant able to   back up server database. so i am created locally . i have two  table name called

```
 1.TP_Users
 2.TP_Roles
```

Following Table below Fields

```
 TP_Users 
 --------
 Id     PK, int, not null
 UserName   nvarchar(50), null
 UserEmail  nvarchar(50), null
 DisplayName nvarchar(50), null
 Password   nvarchar(50), null
 RoleId FK, int, not null        -------------->Foreign key this make Relationship in TP_Roles Id column
 IsActive   bit, not null
 ClientId   int, null
```

Another table TP_Roles following Fields like this

```
 TP_Roles 
 --------
 Id PK, int, not null
 Role_Name  varchar(200), null
 IsActive   bit, null
```

In server database  i seen relationship table 
 i seen Like following

```
FK Name                             Parent tabl name  column_id Refrenced table name    column_id
    FK__Users_cop__RoleI__27AED5D5  TP_Users    RoleId  6      TP_Roles             Id  1 
    FK__Users_cop__RoleI__28A2FA0E  TP_Users    RoleId  6      TP_Roles             Id  1
```

I have See like Relationship server database above like this  but when i create Local database  same like above how can i create  local database

Comment: I think you forgot the question..

Comment: I posted my doubt all @sagi

Comment: edited my question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a foreign key constraint using the [`ALTER TABLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx#TsqlProcedure) DDL statement:

```
ALTER TABLE TP_Users 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_TP_Users_TP_Roles FOREIGN KEY (RoleId)     
    REFERENCES TP_Roles  (Id )     
    ON DELETE CASCADE -- optional   
    ON UPDATE CASCADE -- optional    
;
```

Comment: thank you  i will create   table and use this constraints

Comment: You can also specify the foreign key constraints in the `CREATE TABLE` statement....

Comment: can specify foreign key  constraints  when create table .

Comment: getting Error Like this Msg 1769, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
Foreign key 'FK_TP_Users_TP_Roles' references invalid column 'RoleId' in referencing table 'TP_Users'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 30
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: created  using this like                                                                                Roleid int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TP_Roles(Id)

Comment: Please post a new question with the current create table statements and the error description you get.

Comment: Zohar Created Foreign Relationship Like                                                                                create table TP_Users
(

Id int primary key Not Null,
Username  nvarchar(50) NUll,
UserEmail nvarchar(50) NUll,
DisplayName nvarchar(50) NULL,
Password  nvarchar(50) NULL,
IsActive  bit  Not null,
ClientId  int null,
RoleId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TP_Roles(Id)
 )